# How to destroy pod with status "Unknown" in openshift?

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

My pods are showing status as Unknown; and attempts to scale them down to 0 have failed from command prompt as well as UI.

And this is not allowing me to start new pods as well. See error below:

> Unable to mount volumes for pod
>   "mysql-1-v9lcr_cloud-apps(1e9beb72-e3cf-11e8-943e-02ec8e61afcf)":
>   timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod
>   "cloud-apps"/"mysql-1-v9lcr". list of unmounted volumes=[mysql-data].
>   list of unattached volumes=[mysql-data default-token-zsbnc]

Location: **starter-ca-central-1**

Comment: `oc delete pod <pod name> --now --force` should take care of that pesky pod not dying. For the stuck volume, reach out to the Online community team at https://help.openshift.com/forms/community-contact.html of it persists

Comment: Appreciate your help, force delete as well did not clear the pods; they are still being returned in "oc get pods" output. I have contacted the community.

Comment: My apologies, the correct command is `oc delete pod <pod name> --grace-period=0 --force`

Comment: @WillGordon thanks, it finally worked!!!